# What happened to Dushala, Kauravas’ sister, after the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, kauravas

Duhsala was the only daughter in the long lineage of offsprings of king Dhritrashtra and queen Gandhari. Her childhood was fruitful as she was loved and cared for by the auspicious king and his 100 sons as well as 5 Pandavas.

What happened to Dushala, Kauravas’ sister, after the Mahabharata?

Comment: Question appears copied from [this Quora Q&A](https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-Dushala-Kauravas-sister-after-the-Mahabharata). You didn't find the answer there satisfactory?